# jQueryUI Autocomplete appending menu to wrong element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a text box with auto complete functionality from jQueryUI. I want to append the results to a div with the id of #catcher.  Currently, the results are only appended directly below the text input.  You can see where I tried to specify the appendTo option in the autocomplete initialization, and when I write the appendTo option to the console, it prints the correct id, and yet the results are not appended there.  Why are the results from the autocomplete being appended in the wrong place?

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
            {

                $('#nameAutoComplete').autocomplete(
                {

                    source: ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'],
                    appendTo: '#catcher'

                });
                //prints #catcher to the console
                console.log($('#nameAutoComplete').autocomplete('option', 'appendTo'));


            });
```

HTML

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <input name="nameAutoComplete" type="text" id="nameAutoComplete" />
    //results should be appended here 
    <div  id="catcher"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

CSS

```
#catcher
{
    border: 3px dashed #ccc;
    width:250px;
    min-height:500px;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Make sure the IDs are unique across the page.

Comment: They are.  There's nothing else on the page at the moment.

Comment: It's actually working as it should. If you inspect the catcher element whilst using the autocomplete, you'll see the list appended to it. Your CSS styles are making you think otherwise.

Comment: @MelanciaUK that's strange.  What if a user needed to see autocomplete results on the opposite side of the page from the text box tagged with autocomplete?  Also, how are you inspecting the HTML of the results while the search is active

Comment: I put your code on a jsFiddle and inspected with Firebug (Firefox). You can see the DOM changes going on. Regarding your first question, I don't have a clue.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234802/jqueryui-autocomplete-shown-in-wrong-place-when-using-input-field-in-div-with-po

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it happens because catcher div is floated to right. Not sure. Try removing the float and see.

I have created a fiddle for the same. Not it appends to the catcher element. But not sure what behavior you want after append. May be you can take off from there. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FbRFj/

you can override the internal

```
_renderItem
```

to directly append results to a completely different element,

Comment: I saw something like this in the documentation, but I was under-thinking things and thought it would've been just as easy as telling the computer which element to append to.  This is going to help, though, thanks.